# How to fix redirect to trailing slash with nginx and php backend

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, nginx-location, php-7.2

Like in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088763/how-do-you-fix-nginx-automatically-301-redirecting-to-the-same-url-with-a-traili) i run into the same problem with trailing slashes.

Directory /var/www/services contains several backend services. 
For example, i'm requesting GET `/customer?arg1=1&arg2=2` nginx will always redirects me to `/customer/?arg1=1&arg2=2`.

Nginx log output:

```
172.18.0.6 - - [29/May/2019:14:47:32 +0000] "GET /customer?limit=1&filter%5Bemail%5D=somemail%40gmail.com&filter%5BwebsiteId%5D=1 HTTP/1.1" 301 170 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.29.0 PHP/7.0.33"
172.18.0.6 - - [29/May/2019:14:47:32 +0000] "GET /customer/?limit=1&filter%5Bemail%5D=somemail%40gmail.com&filter%5BwebsiteId%5D=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.29.0 PHP/7.0.33"
```

All other requests, like `customer/count` works as expected.

How can i avoid such undesired behaviour?

Configuration is below:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name api.local;
        root /var/www/services;

        ssl_certificate  /etc/ssl/certs/optimax.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/optimax.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/optimax.pem;

        location ~ ^/(?<ms_dir>[^/]+)/(.*)$ {
                root /var/www/services/$ms_dir/public;
                set $ms_request $2;
                try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ /index\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_pass php72:9001;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $ms_request;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root/$ms_dir/public$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root/$ms_dir/public;
        }

        access_log /dev/stdout;
        error_log /dev/stderr;
        rewrite_log on;
}
```

Comment: Is there a directory called `customer` in the `/var/www/services` directory?

Comment: Yes, there is a `customer` directory in `/var/www/services`, it contains a `public` dir with an index.php file

Comment: The redirection is default behaviour. But the root cause of your problem is that the regular expression does not match `/customer`. You could try: `^/(?<ms_dir>[^/]+)(?:/(.*))?$`

Comment: Now i get rewrite cycle and all other requests get 500 response 
`rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 172.18.0.6, server: api.local, request: "POST /customer/token HTTP/1.1", host: "api.local"
172.18.0.6 - 592bec74-cfa6-48b1-a7da-be765652274c [30/May/2019:07:38:53 +0000] "POST /customer/token HTTP/1.1" 500 178 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.29.0 PHP/7.0.33"`
Could you please explain the second part of expresssion, i cant figure it out a little bit.

Comment: You should reverse the two regular expression location blocks.

Comment: Reverse? What do you mean?

Comment: Regular expression `location` blocks are evaluated in order until a match is found. `/index.php` is now matching the modified regular expression (sorry). But it is easily fixed by moving the `location ~ /index\.php(/|$) { ... }` block **above** the `location ~ ^/(?<ms_dir>[^/]+)(?:/(.*))?$ { ... }` block.

Comment: Thanks alot! Rewrites are gone and other API's requests works fine as i can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Richard Smith's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith) suggestion works perfect.

Updated config below:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name api.local;
        root /var/www/services;

        ssl_certificate  /etc/ssl/certs/optimax.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/optimax.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/optimax.pem;

        location ~ /index\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_pass php72:9001;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $ms_request;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root/$ms_dir/public$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root/$ms_dir/public;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?<ms_dir>[^/]+)(?:/(.*))$ {
                root /var/www/services/$ms_dir/public;
                set $ms_request $2;
                try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        access_log /dev/stdout;
        error_log /dev/stderr;
        rewrite_log on;
}
```